# Como resolver o erro "Unknown user name or password unavailable database alias"?

Tags: firebird, delphi-7

Meu programa é em Delph7, banco BDE, firebird 2.0, mas quando acesso dá o seguinte erro:

> Unknown user name or password unavailable database alias

Como posso resolver este problema?

Comment: Ola Veronica , seja bem vinda ao StackOverFlow Português, vc poderia colocar mais informações na pergunta, por exemplo sua string de conexão e a rotina que cotem o erro, quanto mais informações do problema melhor é para a comunidade ajudar vc.

Comment: este programa estava funcionando teve que formatar o computador e na instalação ficou dando este erro ao abrir o programa. O que faço?

Comment: Ao acessar o BDEAdministrador da este erro também

Answer (score 2):

A mensagem de erro é bem simples e de fácil entendimento!

Nome de usuário ou senha não encontrados no banco de dados, como você teve que formatar e reinstalar novamente, provavelmente você o fez diferente de como fez antes, basta adicionar o nome de usuário e senha (que usou para instalar o *Firebird*) em sua aplicação.

Caso não se lembre que colocou uma senha ou instalou sem usar uma senha, teste usar o acesso padrão do *Firebird*:

```
user: SYSDBA
password: masterkey
```

Comment: Eu consigo conectar o banco no Flame Robin DataBased Admin com essa esse usuario e senha mesmo, mas no  BDE Administrador da este erro " Unknown user name or password unavailable database alias" me ajuda!

Comment: Alguém pode me ajudar neste erro acima???

Comment: Verifica como esta sendo feito o acesso no BDE Administrador, não resta muita coisa a fazer! Se possível, desinstala e reinstala ele!

Comment: eu consegui da seguinte maneira coloquei umas 5 dll na mesma pasta no meu sistema executável ai funcionou. Só que agora ele esta apresentando o seguinte erro na hora que depois que eu gravo um registro no próximo da erro assim " Access violation at address 4D1EE68 in module SQLINT32.DLL. Read of address 00000052"  . Você pode me ajudar???